# Generating EDMX output with PLINQO EF and Oracle takes extremely long or is stuck

Tags: c#, oracle11g, t4, edmx, plinqo

To make a long story short, I am trying to generate a .EDMX file from an Oracle 11g Express database using PLINQO for Entity Framework and CodeSmith 6.5. Rendering the edmx.csp output has been running for 5 minutes as I type this, and I have yet to see any files being created, so I don't know whether something's wrong, or if Oracle is just being Oracle.

One problem I ran into before was an Exception stating that the keyword "multipleactiveresultset" is unknown. I removed it from the .csp template connection string, because I suspect Oracle has no idea what to do with it. I don't know if that's maybe the problem because I don't know how codesmith does what it does.

If anyone has had the same problem, I would appreciate some guidance. Or in the meantime, I would like to know if Oracle has an equivalent to multipleactiveresultsets=true in the connection string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I couldn't find a solution to this. In the end, I installed ODAC into visual studio and generated an EF edmx using visual studio. Note that this is only possible with VS professional or better. VS Express does not support installing thirdparty tools like SQL*Plus.